# Parse and Twilio

Tags: android, parse-platform, twilio

I want to use `Twilio`'s `SMS` and Recorded Voice services, which allow users to send USSD code to update certain object fields on their entry in `parse.com` 's database. Also other users should be able to send different `USSD` code to retrieve very basic information using cloud code. I would like to implement this in two ways:
- send `USSD` code and receive info (written) directly
- Recorded Sound System that helps the user get what he/she needs, similar to the voice service provided by communication companies.

The problem is that I don't know what are the technical names of the specific services/`REST APIs` I need to get this done. After some research I came across `IVR` and `USSD`, are these what I need to explore more?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To get started with Twilio on Parse you should check out the [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-modules-twilio) and these getting started blog posts:

- [Sending SMS with Parse](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/get-started-with-twilio-and-parse-in-the-twilio-cloud-module.html)
- [Making and receiving calls on Parse](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/the-twilio-cloud-module-just-got-even-better/)

If you want to look further into responding to SMS messages, take a look at:

- [This explanation of how Twilio inbound message requests work](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request)
- [This introduction of the Twilio Node.js helper](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html)

If you're looking into building an IVR, take a look at:

- [This IVR building walkthrough](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/ruby/rails) (It's written for Ruby on Rails, but the theory is the same)
- [This Node.js tutorial on building a survey with Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/automated-survey/node/express)

I hope this helps. Let me know if there's anything else I can help with.